# Mozilla: openTab fails in recent version

Tags: firefox-addon

In a Firefox extension, I open new tabs:

```
 var tab = gBrowser.addTab(url, referrer, null, postData, null, null);
```

With Firefox 30, this fails, sometimes, after 9 tabs opened:

```
TypeError: this.selectedItem is null
```

However, the number of tabs does increase by 1 (checked with gBrowser.browsers.length).

I tried this alternative code, but I get the same error after a while:

```
var wm = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
var my_browser = wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser").getBrowser();
var tab = my_browser.addTab(url, referrer, null, postData, null, null);
```

Comment: I can't re-simulate this. Can you provide code that helps us do this. I pasted this code here to scratchpad and was able to run it endlessly: `var tab = gBrowser.addTab('about:blank', null, null, null, null, null);`

Answer (score 0):

Somehow this was fixed by changing some of the custom CSS used to modify the display of the browser

```
#navigator-toolbox {
/*display: none;*/ /* causes crashes!!! */
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#TabsToolbar {
/*display: none;*/ /* causes crashes!!! */
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```